# Finding $\iint_D \nabla \cdot F \; \mathrm{d}A$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want Finding $\iint_D \nabla \cdot F \; \mathrm{d}A$.

Normally I have dealt with $\nabla F$ for $F(x,y,z)=xyz$ sort of cases, where I just then derive it in terms of $x,y,z$ for my $i,j,k$.

Here though, I have $F(x,y) = xy\boldsymbol{i}+x^2\boldsymbol{j}$.

What do I do to find $\nabla \cdot F$ here, use whatever example you wish, just please make it of type $F(x,y) = xy i + xy j$ with whatever $x$ and $y$ you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $F:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$

$\begin{eqnarray}\nabla\cdot F&=&(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y})\cdot(f_{1}(x,y), f_{2}(x,y))^{t}\\
&=& \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y} \end{eqnarray}$

where in the first line is the inner product of those vectors.

In your case

$\begin{eqnarray}\nabla\cdot F&=&(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y})\cdot(xy, x^{2})^{t}\\
&=& y+ 0 \end{eqnarray}$

I hope it helps you :-)

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!